Kafka consumer pauses for approx 18 seconds and then polls the next batch of messages in a spring boot application
In our spring boot application, when we're processing a batch of records, we're using acknowledge.nack() to negatively acknowledge the next batch of records. so that after processing the current batch we shouldn't lose the messages and directly consume the next batch.
After upgrading the dependencies like "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.9.13", 'org.apache.kafka:kalka-clients:3.6.0, and modifying the ack mode to MANUAL IMMEDIATE, our katka consumer pauses for 18-19 seconds and then polls the next set of messages.
Processed messages at 8:00:14

2024-08-06 08:00:14. 0112 INEO [ pool-2-thread-16] : [PP-EVENT-CONSUMER_CHILD] Processed ‹1000> messages by child thread PP-EVENT-CONSUMER THREAD org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-10-C-1:pool-2-thread-16 in <35100> ms

Polled messages ar 8:00:35

2024-08-06 08:00:35.5602 INFO [ntContainer#2-10-C-1] c.u.i.t s.c.RawEventProcessor [PP-EVENT-CONSUMER] Polled 2000 messages by main consumer thread PP-EVENT-CONSUMER_THREAD_org.springframework.kafka.KafkalistenerEndpointContainer#2=10-C-


whereas earlier there’s no delay

2024-07-29 12:31:31.2872 INFO [ poor-2-thread-10］: [PP-EVENT-CONSUMER CHILD] Thread PP-EVENT -CONSUMER THREAD_org.springframework.kafka.KafkalistenexEndpointContainer#2-9-C-1:pool-2-thread-10 Committing Partition - 1
2024-07-29 12:31:31.2872 INFO E pool-2-thread-10] : [PP-EVENT-CONSUMER CHILD] Processed <1000› messages by chi. PP-EVENT-CONSUMER_ THREAD_org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer$2-9-C-1:pool-2-thread-10 in <32149> ms

we tried downgrading individual dependencies but that doesn't helps out. And we've haven't changed any configuration apart from ack mode and allowing circular references to true.
Additionally we tried running the application in debug mode and found out that it’s committing the offsets 1 by 1 and that’s why it’s taking an approx time of 18 seconds.
